# Detecting loops in in in strings

Tags: code-golf, string

Given a string, mark which parts in the string repeat in box brackets, and write how many times it does so before the box.

Example:`st st st Hello ThereThere`
`st`(with a space after) repeats 3 times, `There` repeats 2 times, and `l` repeats 2 times in `Hello`, so the output will be:
`3[st ]He2[l]o 2[There]`
There is no space between `[st ]` and `Hello` because the space in the string is being taken up by the repeating part. `[st ]`, 3 times with a `Hello` after it would be `st st st Hello`, which is what the string has.

Other examples:
`st Hello st st Bye` -> `st He2[l]o 2[st ]Bye`
`Bookkeeper` -> `B2[o]2[k]2[e]per`
`/\/\/\\\\\\\\/\/\/` -> `3[/\]6[\]3[\/]`

Shortestest code wins.

EDIT: To clarify the choice of selections, choose the **largest possible** repeating section, and try and leave as little non-repeating characters as possible. Do not nest boxed-in sections.

Comment: This is ambiguous. For example, `ababababcabcabc` -> `4[ab]2[cab]c`? `4[ab]c2[abc]`? `3[ab]3[abc]`? What bout `abcdefdefghiabcdefdefghi` -> `2[abcdefdefghi]`? `abc2[def]ghiabc2[def]ghi`? `2[abc2[def]ghi]`?

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail: I have elaborated in the recent edit. To answer your questions, `ababababcabcabc` -> `3[ab]3[abc]`, `abcdefdefghiabcdefdefghi` -> `2[abcdefdefghi]`.

Comment: this is not possible ;)  just the typical first answer I get whenever I ask a developer something.

Comment: @kinjal Then you aren't asking the questions the right way. Try to formulate your questions in the form of a coding challenge. So not "Can you do this?" but "Fastest solution wins!"

Comment: Shouldn't the output to your first example be "3[st ]He2[l]o 2[There]"? (Same for the second.)

Comment: @Howard: think of it as RLE for strings, i.e. the repeating strings need to be contiguous.

Comment: @PaulR That's what I said. We have two consecutive `l` inside `Hello`.

Comment: Why gets “st Hello st st Bye” transformed into “st Hello 2[st ]Bye” and not into “st Hello2[ st] Bye”? So the repeating substring why not starts with the first repeated character, the space _before_ “st”?

Comment: @Howard: sorry - I missed the point there - you're right.

Comment: @Howard: Yes, it should be. I overlooked that. manatwork: Try not to have spaces before characters in repeating sequences.

Comment: The specification is still ambiguous because it lists multiple goals without clearly stating their relative priority, and without indicating what level of naïvety is acceptable. I don't see the point in constructing complicated test cases to elucidate the points: either the question needs to be largely rewritten to give precise acceptance criteria or it needs to be amended to indicate that wide latitude will be given.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Perl, 36 bytes

```perl
#!perl -p
s!(.+)\1+!@{[$&=~/\Q$1/g]}."[$1]"!eg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YUUNPWzPGUFvRoTpaRc22Tj8mUMVQPz22Vk8pWsUwVkkxNR2oqkQBgjxSc3LyFUIyUotSwQSXU35@dnZqakFqERdcGqLUqTL1X35BSWZ@XvF/3QIA)

---

### PHP 5.6, 68 bytes

Same code in PHP. Requires the command line option `-F`, and relies on deprecated `/e` modifier.

```php
<?=preg_filter('/(.+)\1+/e','substr_count("\0","\1")."[\1]"',$argn);
```

Answer (score 3):

### C, <strike>224 205 203 199 195</strike> 193 chars

The string is given as program parameter. As usual, use double quotes if your string contains spaces, and for empty strings - calling the program without any parameter crashes, but calling with `""` works.

Output for test cases is:

```
st st st Hello ThereThere => 3[st ]He2[l]o 2[There]
Bookkeeper                => B2[o]2[k]2[e]per
/\/\/\\\\\\\\/\/\/        => 3[/\]2[\\\]3[\/]
```

which looks correct to me regarding "choose the largest possible repeating section".

Code:

```
l,r,f,i;char*c;main(a,b)char**b;{l=strlen(c=b[1]);for(;putchar(*c);c++)for(a=l;--a;f=0)for(r=a;!f;r+=a){for(i=0;i<a;)f|=r>l||c[i]-c[r+i++];if(f*r>a)c[a]=0,printf("\b%i[%s]",r/a,c),c+=r-1,a=1;}}
```

Answer (score 3):

### scala, 102 chars

```
print("(?!\\s)(.+)\\1+".r.replaceAllIn(readLine,m=>m.matched.size/m.group(1).size+"["+m.group(1)+"]"))
```

**Output**

```
st st st Hello ThereThere ->    3[st ]He2[l]o 2[There]
st Hello st st Bye        ->    st He2[l]o 2[st ]Bye
Bookkeeper                ->    B2[o]2[k]2[e]per
/\/\/\\\\\\\\/\/\/        ->    3[/\]2[\\\]3[\/]
```

Comment: +1, nice use of `Regex.Match`

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>40</s> <s>37</s> 24 bytes

```
(.+)(\1)+
$.($#2*__)[$1]
```

-13 bytes thanks to *@Neil*.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X0NPW1MjxlBTm0tFT0NF2UgrPl4zWsUw9v//4hIFCPJIzcnJVwjJSC1KBRMA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8F9DT1tTI8ZQU5tLRU9DRdlIKz5eM1rFMPb//@ISBQjySM3JyVcIyUgtSgUTXHAxiLxTZSqXU35@dnZqakFqEZd@DAhCAZjDlZiUnJKaBkTpGZnIbAA). (NOTE: Slightly different results for some test cases in comparison to the challenge description, but still the same as the accepted answer, so I assumed both are valid.)

**Explanation:**

```python
(.+)(\1)+       # Look for the repeated sections (where the repeated string is captured in
                # group 1, and every time it's repeated in group 2)
```

Example: in the input `"st st st Hello ThereThere"` it will find the capture group 1 and 2 as: `"st "` & `["st ","st "]`; `"l"` & `["l"]`; and `"There"` & `["There"]` respectively.

```python
   $#2          # Get the amount of times group 2 was repeated
      *_        # Converted to unary (that amount of '_')
        _       # + 1 (with an additional '_' added)
$.(      )      # Convert that unary back to a number again by taking the length
          [$1]  # And append the match of the first capture group between block-quotes
                # after the number
```

Example: `"st st st "` will become `"3[st ]"`; `"ll"` will becomes `"2[l]"`; and `"ThereThere"` will become `"2[There]"`. So `"st st st Hello ThereThere"` is now the intended result `"3[st ]He2[l]o 2[There]"` (which is output implicitly).

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 41 bytes

```perl
s|(.+)\1+|(length($&)/length$1)."[$1]"|ge
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@4RkNPWzPGULtGIyc1L70kQ0NFTVMfwlQx1NRTilYxjFWqSU8FKi1RgCCP1JycfIWQjNSiVDDB5ZSfn52dmlqQWsQFl4YodapM/ZdfUJKZn1f8X7cAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 82 bytes

```powershell
[regex]::Replace($args,'(.+)\1+',{$a,$g=$args|% gr*
"$($a.Length/$g.Length)[$g]"})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZBPa8MgGIfv@RQS7Iyra1hyCxRGTj3sNHYzMkr7zkDCzDRjHWk@e/aqXZj/0Iffo/IO5husa6HvF/pO9mRapAUNF1VVLzD0xxNk9Gi1EyzbbXnzuGViokdB9T7g64Zoe5@kFFO7Z/jQY5tTfdtxSbVKZ77MSfKUJQSbyJgbSRwHfNSQ1xYshIUJVkrk6gCF7JUhhQxcMf7PjVa8of5BiUQalEIiVoGvTm1M1wEMYH22LqRRhexwgvJszeWN77cWDj5fyrzBLCJVyib3f@HkSjZkCh51gsJlgNMIZ6wefYvUgvvqRwR3WFTqAvQ1ivwBPleJV3/pNJmXXw)