# Shorten text with Run Length Encoding

Tags: code-golf, string, encoding

Shorten (or not) text using run length encoding

**Input:**

```
heeeello
woooorld
```

**Output:**

```
1h4e2l1o
1w4o1r1l1d
```

- Read lines from stdin.
- Print to stdout.
- Stderr is of course discarded.
- Assume there are hidden testcases (no embedding of the output)
- Input/Output as ASCII
- Any language is accepted

Comment: You can (typically) save quite a bit if you ignore all ones, e.g. `w4orld` instead of `1w4o1r1l1d` (you'd need to escape numerics, e.g. `f111 -> f3\1´). But then it would be a near-duplicate of this: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6774

Comment: As it is it's close enough to [Run-Length Encoding](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1015/run-length-encoding) that I vote to close as dupe. It's not going to provide any new challenge or points of interest.

Comment: Bonus points for whoever manages to find a fixpoint.

Comment: Run-Length Encoding may be the same at its core but the input format and the required output format are very different.

Comment: @FUZxxl, `22` is a trivial fixpoint.

Comment: @PeterTaylor And the only nonempty one. We know it must begin with a digit. `11` is impossible. `22` must end there or be followed by another fixed point not beginning with `2`. `333nnn` is an impossible pattern, for you'll never find the same character at consecutive odd indices. `4444` and up fail for the same reason.

Comment: DIfferent input and output formats are not enough to render questions distinct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run-Length Encoding](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1015/run-length-encoding)

Comment: @pppery I prefer to close that one as a duplicate of this one, since this one is for text, not just numbers.

Comment: @Khuldraesethna'Barya: Are we assuming that runs are limited to 9 repeats?  Or are the numbers variable-width, like `33a` would be 33 repeats of `a`?  Question doesn't say, and existing answers seem to just count without limiting to 9.  IDK if that introduces more fixed points, but it does make the question under-specified.  (I think to be unambiguous, the encoding would need to handle a thirty-three `a` run as `9a9a9a6a`, not `33a`, unless ASCII digits aren't allowed in the input.)

Answer (score 4):

## Perl: <del>46</del> → 36 or 27 characters

<del>`perl -pe's|((.)\2*)|@x=split//,$1;@x.$x[0]|eg'`</del>

All hail @ardnew for coming up with the idea of using the `tr///c` operator to count the number of characters in the matched string instead of splitting:

```
perl -pe's|((.)\2*)|$1=~y///c.$2|eg'
```

Degolfed:

```
while(defined($_ = <>)) {
  $_ =~ s{((.)\2*)}           # match 1 or more consecutive identical non-newlines
         {
           ($1 =~ y///c )     # count the number of characters in $1
           .                  # and concatenate it
           $2                 # with the first matched character
         }eg;                 # execute substitution, match "global"
  print $_;                   # print the modified line
}
```

Usage:

```
$ perl -pe's|((.)\2*)|$1=~y///c.$2|eg' infile
```

or via STDIN

```
$ perl -pe's|((.)\2*)|$1=~y///c.$2|eg'
heeeello
```

prints

```
1h4e2l1o
```

Comment: You're short-changing yourself on your character count - I count 37 characters including 1 for the `p` option.

Comment: You can save 10 chars by using `s|((.)\2*)|$1=~y///c.$2|eg`, which sums to 27 total chars (using the same character counting rules as @Gareth)

Comment: Can shorten even further to 25 bytes (including `-p`) by eliminating the outer parens: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YR0NPM8ZQS0dFzbauUl9fP1lPxVAnPfX//4xUIMjJyf@XX1CSmZ9X/F/X11TPwNDgv24BAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ûèB☼å°╤
```

[Run and debug it st staxlang.xyz!](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=968a420f86f8d1&i=heeeello%0Awoooorld)

#### Unpacked (8 bytes) and explanation:

```
m|RFNppz
m           For each line of input:
 |R           Run-length encode: "heeeello" -> [[104,1],[101,4],[108,2],[111,1]]
   F          For each pair:
    N           Uncons-left: [104,1] -> push [104]; push 1
     ppz        Pop and print. Pop and print. Push "".
              Implicit print (always an empty string) with a newline
```

#### 5 bytes, works only on a single line:

```
∩l↨me
|RmEp]    Unpacked
|R        Run-length encode: "heeeello" -> [[104,1],[101,4],[108,2],[111,1]]
  m       Map block over input:
   E        Explode array: [104,1] -> push 104, push 1
    p       Pop and print with no newline
     ]      Make a one-element list: 104 -> [104] (which is "h")
            Implicit print with newline
```

[Run and debug it at staxlang.xyz!](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=ef6c176d65&i=heeeello)

Perhaps not legal. This program prints each pair on a line of its own. A bit sketchy.

If that output format is illegal, I give you **6 bytes**:

```
╡δôZ→╬
|RFEp]p    Unpacked
  F        For each item in array, execute block:
      p      Pop and print with no newline
             No implicit print in for-each block, so no extra newlines
```

[Run and debug it at staxlang.xyz!](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=b5eb935a1ace&i=heeeello)

The language's creator [recursive](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/527/recursive) points out that uncons-right (`N`) can shorten this to six bytes unpacked, as it handles the `E` and the `]` on its own. Programs this short, however, often get no shorter when packed, and this is am example. Still six bytes: [`|RFNpp`](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%7CRFNpp&i=heeeello) Edit: Had to update my main answer; this form is what I used.

Comment: NIcely done.  `|RFNpp` can give the specified output in 6 bytes unpacked, but unfortunately, doesn't pack.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Yep. Whoops.

Answer (score 3):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 28 bytes

```
{,/($#:'c),'*:'c:(&~=':x)_x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/v1pHX0NF2Uo9WVNHXQtIWWmo1dmqW1VoxlfUKmWkAkFOTr5CeT4QFOWkKP3/DwA)

On mobile, explanation to follow...

Comment: I think three bytes can be [saved](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/v1pHv1pDRblCU0erolZdQ63OVt2qQjO@olYpIxUIcnLyFcrzgaAoJ0Xp/38A) with `{($#x),*x}'` instead of `($#:'c),'*:'c:`

Answer (score 3):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), <s>150</s> <s>144</s> 134 bytes

```scala
io.Source.stdin.getLines.map(s=>println{val(x,y,z)=s.tail./:(("",s.head,1)){case((a,b,c),d)=>if(b==d)(a,b,c+1)else(a+c+b,d,1)};x+z+y})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYtBDsIgEEX3PcXEFQRC41aDiXt3nmCAscUgrR001aZnrzau/Lv38j57TLh07kq@wBFoLJQDw7HvJ6hryF2Bge6POFCAmOG85sAtpbTEzpy7x@DJcAkxm4bKKWZic8NesD30Q8wl5emJSYz6pd/SsikYk6l3Qmw2mk1LGPRWyskjkxConfZSB2kP8SKctUH@nNpKSt8ClVdOr5d5P6q3es1ymRdc55zzPtClaZrqX/xjhR8)

**UPDATE**:

- 6 bytes saved thanks to @Kjetil S.
- 10 bytes saved thanks to @user

Here the pure Lambda de-golfed (97 bytes):

```scala
  s => {
    val (x,y,z) = s.tail./:(("", s.head, 1)) {
      case ((a, b, c), d) =>
        if (b == d)
          (a, b, c + 1)
        else
          (a + c + b, d, 1)
    }
    x+z+y
  }
```

Comment: You could cut `scala.` before io. Also I think some surrrounding code can be removed from the count. Only include the lambda to get 110 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYsxjsMgEEV7n2KUCgQiSh0RKX26nGCAsc0KgZchKyeWz@6NlSq/e0/vs8eEW3E/5BtcgeZGOTBcp2mB4xFyaVDp9xErBYgZ7nsOPFJKXSzmXh7Vk@EWYjYDtVvMxKYvldCPYmN7mWrMLeXlD5OY9VO/pGXTMKZ3lcKN@ibE4aDZjIRBn6RcPDIJgdppL3WQ9hJ74awN8uPUSVJ6F6i8cnq/rOdZvdRz3eS64T7nnPeB@mEYum/xjR3@Aw "Scala – Try It Online")

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that `scala.` is obsolete, which saves 6 bytes.
Regarding the lambda: I agree that it is generally ok to provide just a lambda. However, this challenge mentions explicitly that the solution should read from stdin and print to stdout, and other solutions (e.g., Python) do also include this in their byte count, so I think it is fair to keep it.

Comment: You can use `map` instead of `foreach`, and `/:` instead of `foldLeft`.

Comment: I really feel bad to use `map` for side-effects, but, hey, this is golfing, so it's a great tip :) Also I did not know about the `/:` alias, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 74 bytes

```
D,g,@:,BGd€q$€bLzBFJ
D,f,@,10C$t€g
]getchar
y:''
Wx,`y,+x,`x,]getchar
$f>y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99FJ13HwUrHyT3lUdOaQhUgkeRT5eTmxeWik6bjoGNo4KxSAhRM54pNTy1Jzkgs4qq0UlfnCq/QSajU0QaSFTpwGZU0u8r//zNSgSAnJ5@rPB8IinJSAA)

This could be [half the size](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99FJ13HwUrHyT3lUdOaQhUgkeRT5eTmxeWjY2jgrFICFEj/r5KTmJuUkqhgaGf//39GKhDk5ORzlecDQVFOCgA) if we could take input from the command line

### How it works

The first line (the function `g`) actually performs RLE. The rest of it just reads the input char by char, passes it to a function `f`, which splits on newlines, then runs `g` on each line.

`g` simply groups equal adjacent characters with `BG`, then gets the lengths (`€bL`) and deduplicates (`€q`). We then `z`ip these together, flatten, `J`oin and print.

Comment: Remind me to upvote this in 20m :p

Answer (score 2):

### J, <strike>35</strike> 31 characters

```
,(](":@#,{.);.1~1,2~:/\])1!:1[1
```

Usage:

```
   ,(](":@#,{.);.1~1,2~:/\])1!:1[1
heeeello
1h4e2l1o
   ,(](":@#,{.);.1~1,2~:/\])1!:1[1
woooorld
1w4o1r1l1d
```

Comment: Using modern site rules and a function, `[:,(#,&":{.)/.~` for 15: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o610NJR11JSsqvU09fXq/mtycaUmZ@QrqBtmmKQa5RjmqyvoWimkKahnpAJBTk6@Oky@3CTfsMgwxzAFpqI8HwiKclLU/wMA "J – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 84 bytes

```python
def f(s,c=1):i,*j=s;b=j[:1]==[i];print(end='%s%s'%(c,i)*(b^1));f(j,1+b*c)
f(input())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcxBDoMgEADAO6/Yi2HXcqG9YXiJsU1EiBgDBDDV11OTzgMmXXWN4dVczPABH0CKp2JQ86XsaQ1yzttiHTgswmhJyot@02WY9TYqOWk9@mlI2YeKNiyad6UrvEMjPPU4vyXR4HAT8jH3hphDH9JRkajBPRMDexqbqvoP1FZ72/fIvvGW9@UH)

## Explanation

Checks if the first and second characters of the string are equal. If they are, increase the counter by 1. If they are not, print the counter and the first item and reset the counter to 1. In both cases, the function is called recursively with the first character removed.

Raises an error when end of string is reached.

---

Without I/O restrictions, but with minimal byte count:

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 70 bytes

```python
f=lambda s:'%s%s'%(len(s)-len(t:=s.lstrip(p:=s[0])),p)+f(t)if s else''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYhBCoMwEADvfUUQQnZpFaGXIviS4sFigoFtsmQXpK@P8dK5zDD80z2n54tLrWGm9fvZViOTs2LFWSCfQLC/pNMsA4mWyMCt3@OC@GC8B1CMwYjxJN65yiUmhQDd7htEuUO8/eeRG4W2NusJ)

[Python 3 equivalent](https://tio.run/##PYq7CsMwDAD3foUJGFv0AaVbQr6kdItEDMIWlkro17vq0lsOjpOP7a0@xtiQAmWFWVZ9zvfXYqveWK0XyQJLR3v3mqJGTTEzVl@vPxlcBM7kLhQ0ICumNKSXapnytKPD3CaA0z8ezem8eRxf) (77 bytes)

## Explanation

Strips all repeating characters off the start of the string. Then it returns a string containing (1.) the difference in lengths between the original string and the stripped string; (2.) the first character of the original string; (3.) the result of the recursive function applied to the stripped string. Recursion ends when an empty string is encountered.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
|εÅγs.ιJ,
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/5tzWw63nNhfrndvppfP/f0YqEOTk5HOV5wNBUU7Kf13dvHzdnMSqSgA)

Or alternatively:

```
|εÅγøí˜J,
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/5tzWw63nNh/ecXjt6TleOv//Z6QCQU5OPld5PhAU5aT819XNy9fNSayqBAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
|          # Read all lines of input as list
 ε         # For-each over the lines:
  Åγ       #  Run-length encode, pushing the list of characters and lengths separately
    s      #  Swap so the characters at at the top and lengths below it
     .ι    #  Interleave the two lists
       J   #  Join the list of characters and lengths together to a single string
        ,  #  And output it with trailing newline

|εÅγ       # Same as above
    ø      #  Zip/transpose; creating pairs of [character, length]
     í     #  Reverse each pair to [length, character]
      ˜    #  Deep flatten the pairs to a single list
       J,  #  Join them together to a single string, and output it with trailing newline
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 42 bytes

```ruby
->s{s.gsub(/(.)\1*/){|m|"#{m.size}"+m[0]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcZBEoIgFADQqzDfjWahHUBnPAex0AnTGRCGL2kBZycWvdWzbvqkuUu3Hj3SF7qpbEpaPe6XpvJBBSi8orh@RYRasZbHmIzbkTBYRCalhiscOrPymTv85W6aWLchOZZxRy3ewgKnajQ@nGFmJ4/pBw)

Comment: Recently re-visited this and noticed you can replace `m[0]` with `$1` for -2 and if you switch to `ruby -p` you can drop the `->s{s.` ... `}` for another -7 :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 98 bytes

```
Print[""<>StringCases[#,s:x_..:>ToString@StringLength@s<>x]]&/@StringSplit[$ScriptInputString,"
"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE7876Zg@z@gKDOvJFpJycYuuATITHdOLE4tjlbWKbaqiNfTs7ILyYeIO0Aon9S89JIMh2Ibu4rYWDV9qGhwQU5mSbRKcHJRZkGJZ15BaQlEXEeJSyn2//@MVCDIycnnKs8HgqKcFC4jIwA)

A more flexible I/O format reduces this solution to **54 bytes**:

```
""<>StringCases[#,s:x_..:>ToString@StringLength@s<>x]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE7876Zg@19JycYuuKQoMy/dObE4tThaWafYqiJeT8/KLiQfIu4AoXxS89JLMhyKbewqYtWAWvUdFKqVMlKBICcnX0lHQak8HwiKclJAbCMjpdr//3ULgBpLAA)

Comment: If you are wondering why this code does not work in Mathematica's front end (but works fine in TIO and in WolframScript): [There are significant differences between the input parsers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/203434/26598).

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 2 bytes

```
e`
```

`` e` `` is a built-in for run-length encoding. CJam's implicit output ignores array brackets, and so turns `[[1 'h] [2 'e]]` into `"1h2e"`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1fHV/wPzXhf75ffi1XtFJGak5OvkJ5flFOipKCUlJiHhACGYZGxiamZuYWlkB2RioQAFVxlecDAURhYlIyUEkqBOSDgVKs6n8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 10 bytes

```
m(ṁ§:osL←g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P1fj4c7GQ8ut8ot9HrVNSP///3@0UkYqEOTk5CvpKJXnA0FRTopSLAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 78 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
m@main=getLine>>=putStrLn.(>>=shows.length<*>take 1).group>>m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XccxDoAgDADA3Vc4qgOJuzYOjmy@oIkNEAslUOPz0dnbzmO9iLm1ELMU7XdUNDZU7eIWMaTVkdqQCGDNtx5abDLDl@rlqYYpOfXLBIoX9fNoXJE7A8TWPH2YpXt@pPD5Ag)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
Åγsø˜
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cOu5zcWHd5ye8/9/RioQ5OTkAwA)

```
Åγsø˜  # full program
    ˜  # flatten each sublist of...
   ø   # list of all elements of...
Åγ     # chars and corresponding run lengths of chars in...
       # implicit input...
   ø   # with each element from...
  s    # second...
   ø   # sublist paired with corresponding element in...
  s    # first...
   ø   # sublist
       # implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (V8), 66 bytes

*-10 thanks to @Original Original Original VI*

```js
r=>r.split`
`.map(d=>d.replace(/(.)\1*/g,g=>g.length+g[0])).join`
`
```

My first time using `\1` in a regular expression, which is a super overpowered way to approach this problem (looks like a few answers already use it). The rest of the code is basically just I/O.

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, 116 bytes

```scala
_ split "\n"map{def d:Seq[_]=>Any={case e+:f=>val(g,h)=f span e.==
""+e+(g.size+1)+d(h)case x=>x}
d(_)}mkString "\n"
```

[Try it online!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Q3M5rRPKQQmxKqpZpBbfEA)

Is it short? No. Does it use best practices where it wouldn't make the code longer? No. Did I do it for ethical reasons? No. Is it creative? No. Am I proud of it? Yes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 11 bytes

```
ḅ⟨{lṫ}ch⟩ᵐc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3w/@GO1kfzV1TnPNy5ujY549H8lUDB5P//o5UyUoEgJydfSUepPB8IinJSgExHKAAy8/IVikrzihXKMxJLivNTy1KLlGIB)

(If output *really* has to be on stdout, add one byte for `w` at the end.)

```
          c    The output is the concatenation of
 ⟨    c ⟩ᵐ     the concatenated pairs of
  {lṫ}         length converted to a string
       h       and first element
ḅ        ᵐ     for every run in the input.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) iterative, <s>115</s> <s>99</s> 97 bytes

```python
while 1:
 a=b='';k=0
 for c in input():e=a!=c;b+=(str(k)+a)*e;k+=1-k*e;a=c
 print(b[1:]+str(k)+a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYqxCsMgFAB3v@J1ilYKlW7K@5KQQa1FUVSMIeTrjVOPG264enVf8meM04fkQEgCGg0ui4r4JvArDSyEPK1Hp0w61A@0ynCke280Mq7Z06nIUbziDI2WQG0hd2pWITf@v8bwbpJSIWeZtPS9AQ)

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) recursive, <s>136</s> <s>130</s> 129 bytes

```python
f=lambda r,c,s,k=1:s and(c==s[0]and f(r,c,s[1:],k+1)or f(r+str(k)+c,s[0],s[1:]))or r[1:]+str(k)+c
while 1:print(f('','',input()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcmxCsMgGATgPU/hFn90iHQTfJLgYGNE0aqoIfTprbbQ44bjvvxuNsVH70YE9XpqhQo9aKVeMF6RihofQtR9k2Mig7@4My6pJwxSmReprWAPZMomfwzTylx/XW7rwokYz8XFhg1eVzrqYr4aBoDe7TkSQlruNFKC/gA)

The iterative approach seems quite successful, while the recursive version has a lot of room for improvement.

Comment: Nice approach! It looks like the `while` loop in your code is only there to demonstrate the input. Without it, your code is still valid. In that case, the loop does not need to be part of the code and you can reduce the first example to 85 bytes like so: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYwxDgIhFAV7ToE0CxITiR3kn8RYAH4DgQBhMaunRyonr5jiZdp3hFpu8wgxI1UaP@g5Y2xacLBtJsGVvGqnnsay1t6DC41gT@CNk8D30XkS0oozmiRBXdISC560Hsvg7q70Q/5Pc5XFDLjIuZKjLnp@/gA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Your second example can be reduced to 121 bytes like this: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pc1BCsMgEAXQfU4h2WQGXUS6C3iS4CKNihKrQS1pT2@1hX5m8flvMee72Bhu9bLOa8IX/dI7jONYjfDb4642ktjOMjsEXzLZgoJdiLzOslVi4IsrXyQ7KMeY@kRzSXAg7TLLH2O31NtfhzO5UMDANLF2LpzPAohY23esVrd4H4crtiSvPg "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Yea, the while loop is only for linewise input. But the question requires to read _all_ lines, not just one, so externalising the loop would be against the rules.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.1](http://julialang.org/), <s>94</s> <s>84</s> 81 bytes

```julia
foldl(((n,l),c)->(c==l||print(n,l);((c==l&&n)+1,c)),readline()*'\n',init=("",""))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcoxCoAwDEDRu3Soicahs9STuEhbMRJSkQoO3r1K//j4xy28uqfWLUsUAFASpIDjDMF7ed/zYi1NJ2hkreLg/gXpSmsU1gTYd4t2xMrFgzFkDGKte/oTyR8)

Comment: Here is [80 bytes](https://tio.run/##HcgxDoAgDADA3WcwSKtdmA38xQDGmqYag4mDn/ErfgyNN95yCI/urBWUBEP0EL2X69p21vLfAH@1rWLvKCI20ypJINCexySsGbCzz22JlYsHY8gYxFrn/BFZXw). I think it can go shorter though

Comment: Unfortunately, your code didn't work on Julia 1.1 for me. I still managed to get 81 by adding an extra `'\n' ` to `readline()` instead of printing the last tuple manually

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 12 bytes

```
(.)\1*
$.0$1
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X0NPM8ZQi0tFz0AFyMtIBYKcnHyu8nwgKMpJAQA)

**Explanation:**

Get a part of 1 or more of the same character, capturing the character in capture group 1.

```
(.)\1*
```

Replace it with the length of the total match, concatted with the character from capture group 1:

```
$.0$1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), `d`, 2 bytes

```
øe
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=d&code=%C3%B8e&inputs=woooorld&header=&footer=)

That is,

```
øe  # run length encode the implicit input
    # the d flag deep sums the top of the stack before outputting
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <strike>6</strike> 5 bytes

```
jksr8
```

Relatively self explanatory, just joins together Pyth's run length encode instruction

Edit: -1 byte because while working on something completely different I remembered flattening a 2D list is just summing the elements.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PytbL6/I4v9/pYxUIMjJyVcCAA)

Answer (score 0):

### Zsh, 117

```
while read s;do n=1;for i in {1..$#s};do if [[ $s[i] != $s[i+1] ]];then echo -n $n$s[i];n=0;fi;((n++));done;echo;done
```

Run it like this:

```
zsh script.zsh < infile
```

#### De-golfed

```zsh
while read s; do                      # while stdin has more
  n=1                                 # repeat counter
  for i in {1..$#s}; do               # for each character
    if [[ $s[i] != $s[i+1] ]]; then   # same as next one?
      echo -n $n$s[i]                 # print if no
      n=0
    fi
    ((n++))
  done
  echo                                # newline between words
done
```

Comment: Are those white spaces necessary or can you shorten `if [' to 'if[' etc?

Comment: The `[[` construct is a command on it's own (like `[`) and has to be separated from other commands. As to using `[` over `[[`, it requires the arguments to be quoted so four `"` need to be added.

Answer (score 0):

## Bash: 104 characters

```bash
while read s;do e=;while [[ $s ]];do c=${s:0:1};n=${s##+($c)};e+=$[${#s}-${#n}]$c;s=$n;done;echo $e;done
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.2$ while read s;do e=;while [[ $s ]];do c=${s:0:1};n=${s##+($c)};e+=$[${#s}-${#n}]$c;s=$n;done;echo $e;done <<END
heeeello
woooorld
END
1h4e2l1o
1w4o1r1l1d
```

Answer (score 0):

## Burlesque (17B)

```
{=[{J[-jL[Q}\m}WL

{=[{^^[~\/L[Sh}\m}WL
```

Older/Alternative and longer versions:

```
{=[{^^L[Sh\/-]Sh.+}m[\[}WL
{=[{^^L[Sh\/-][-.+}m[\[}WL
{=[{^^L[Sh\/-~.+}m[\[}WL
{=[{^^L[Sh\/-].+}\m}WL
{=[{^^L[Sh\/[~.+}\m}WL
{=[{^^L[Sh\/[~_+}\m}WL
{=[{^^L[Sh\/fc.+}\m}WL
{=[{^^L[Sh\/-~.+}\m}WL
{=[{^^L[Sh\/-]\/}\m}WL
```

Answer (score 0):

### APL (24)

```
,↑{(⍕⍴⍵),⊃⍵}¨B⊂⍨B≠¯1⌽B←⍞
```

Answer (score 0):

## [rs](https://github.com/kirbyfan64/rs), 19 chars

This doesn't really count because I created rs *way* after this was posted...but it was fun anyway!

```
(.)(\1*)/(^^\1\2)\1
```

[Try it here!](http://kirbyfan64.github.io/rs/index.html?script=(.)(%5C1*)%2F(%5E%5E%5C1%5C2)%5C1%0A&input=heeeello%0Awoooorld%0A)

Comment: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12877/lets-allow-newer-languages-versions-for-older-challenges

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/), 44 bytes

[44 bytes: try it online](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn9PzU5I19BpVqj2MpK07C2piKxKL1YQTfPsKY0L7NQQTe5pqRIQTdFISYmL0bhfy1XmoJSRioQ5OTkx@SV5wNBUU6K0n8A). Based on [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1029/15940).

```zsh
echo ${(s::)1}|xargs -n1|uniq -c|tr -d \\n\
```

---

[70 bytes: try it online](https://tio.run/##HYlBCsMgFAX3OcVrGkRx06zVk1gXoRoU5P9iC0Ivb5PMaob5ffLoudSElraIbhB5Km7s3CAludUUre29G9JaKe@xdF8Cbu4SvQaEIMS7FfruWOi6QpB7TOmVeUSmBAsrz8Kc00Gt/KTOB63GWY0/). Based on [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7323/15940).

```zsh
for ((n=1;i++<#w;n++))[[ $w[i] != $w[i+1] ]]&&printf $n$w[i]&&n=0
echo
```

Comment: Note to self: Try using the [mode of an array..](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216158/15940)

Comment: See also [this crazy solution for 28 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1029/15940)