# Mode (most common element) of a list

Tags: code-golf, array

Write a snippet to calculate the mode (most common number) of a list of positive integers.

For example, the mode of

```
d = [4,3,1,0,6,1,6,4,4,0,3,1,7,7,3,4,1,1,2,8]
```

is `1`, because it occurs the maximum of 5 times.

You may assume that the list is stored in a variable such as `d` and has a unique mode.

e.g.: Python, 49

```
max(((i,d.count(i))for i in set(d)), key=lambda x:x[1])
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest solution in bytes wins.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## K5, 6 bytes

```
*>#:'=
```

The first (`*`) of the descending elements (`>`) of the count of each (`#:'`) of the group (`=`). Step by step:

```
  i
4 3 1 0 6 1 6 4 4 0 3 1 7 7 3 4 1 1 2 8

  =i
4 3 1 0 6 7 2 8!(0 7 8 15
 1 10 14
 2 5 11 16 17
 3 9
 4 6
 12 13
 ,18
 ,19)

  #:'=i
4 3 1 0 6 7 2 8!4 3 5 2 2 2 1 1

  >#:'=i
1 4 3 7 6 0 8 2

  *>#:'=i
1
```

[try it in your browser](http://johnearnest.github.io/ok/index.html?run=%20*%3E%23%3A'%3D4%203%201%200%206%201%206%204%204%200%203%201%207%207%203%204%201%201%202%208)!

Answer (score 29):

### Python 2 - 18

```
max(d,key=d.count)
```

Since your python answer doesn't seem to print, I expect this is what you want.

Add 6 bytes for `print`  normally.

Comment: perfect, think @globby needs to see future :)

Comment: The great thing about this one is that it's not even golfy, it's just Pythonic. The only thing that's been golfed is a space between `d,` and `key=`.

Comment: @WChargin: Eh, Pythonic would be to avoid the quadratic runtime by using `defaultdict(int)` or `Counter`. Something like `Counter(d).most_common()[0]`.

Answer (score 27):

## Matlab/Octave, <s>7</s> 5 bytes

Unsurprisingly there's a built-in function for finding modes. As an anonymous function:

```
@mode
```

This returns the most commonly occuring element in the input vector with ties going to the smaller value.

Saved 2 bytes thanks to Dennis!

Comment: +1, clearly the right tool for the job. As it's a builtin, what happens if there's more than one number of highest frequency?

Comment: @steveverrill According to the documentation (type `help mode`): "If two, or more, values have the same frequency 'mode` returns the smallest."

Comment: Unnamed functions seem to be allowed (the accepted answer is one), so you could shorten this to `@mode`.

Comment: @Dennis Thanks! Though I admit it's a strange feeling to edit my first answer on the site.

Answer (score 16):

### [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth) - 6

```
eo/QNQ
```

[Try it online.](http://isaacg.scripts.mit.edu/pyth/index.py)

Expects input on stdin like `[4,3,1,0,6,1,6,4,4,0,3,1,7,7,3,4,1,1,2,8]`. Ties are resolved by last occurrence because Python performs stable sorts.

Sorts the list by count the value in the list, then prints the last number of the list.

`Q` could be replaced with `d` if you initialized `d` to contain the value before e.g. `=d[4 3 1 0 6 4 4 0  1 7 7 3 4 1 1 2 8)`

Python-esque pseudo-code:

```
Q=eval(input());print(sorted(Q,key=Q.count)[-1])
```

Full Explanation:

```
            : Q=eval(input()) (implicit)
e           : ... [-1]
 o   Q      : orderby(lambda N: ...,Q)
  /QN       : count(Q,N)
```

Pyth's `orderby` runs exactly like Python's `sorted` with `orderby`'s first argument being the `key` argument.

Answer (score 12):

## Mathematica, 25 bytes

```
Last@SortBy[d,d~Count~#&]
```

or

```
#&@@SortBy[d,-d~Count~#&]
```

As in the challenge, this expects the list to be stored in `d`.

### or... 15 bytes

Of course, Mathematica wouldn't be Mathematica if it didn't have a built-in:

```
#&@@Commonest@d
```

`Commonest` returns a list of all most common elements (in case of a tie), and `#&@@` is a golfed `First@`.

Comment: another case for mthmca

Answer (score 9):

## CJam, <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
A{A\-,}$0=
```

Assumes the array in a variable called `A`. This is basically sorting the array based on the occurrence of each number in the array and then picks the last element of the array.

Example usage

```
[1 2 3 4 4 2 6 6 6 6]:A;A{aA\/,}$W=
```

Output

```
6
```

1 byte saved thanks to Dennis!

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

Comment: `A{A\-,}$0=` is one byte shorter.

Comment: As of 0.6.5 it's doable in 8 bytes: `Ae\`$e_W=`

Comment: @MartinEnder Umm... [nope](//cjam.aditsu.net#code=%22acbcdcecfff%22e%60%24e_W%3D%0A%0Ae%23%20'c%20appears%204%20times%2C%20'f%20appears%203%20times.%20'f%20is%20returned.). I knew you need to sort first.

Comment: @ErikGolferエリックゴルファー whoops, you're right, needs 9 bytes: `$e\`$e_W=`

Answer (score 9):

## Ruby, 22 bytes

```
d.max_by{|i|d.count i}
```

Basically a port of my Mathematica answer, except Ruby has a direct `max_by` so I don't need to sort first.

Comment: I was about to suggest `d.max_by d.method:count` but that's about a million (aka not even two) bytes longer. Still, it's worth noting that it's possible.

Answer (score 9):

## R, <s>33</s> 25 bytes

Thanks @Hugh for the help shortening:

```
names(sort(-table(d))[1])
```

---

The original:

```
v=table(d);names(v[which.max(v)])
```

This calculates the frequency of each element in the vector `d`, then returns the name of the column containing the largest value. The value returned is actually a character string containing the number. It didn't say anywhere that that wasn't okay, so...

Any suggestions to shorten this are welcome!

Comment: `names(sort(-table(d))[1])`

Answer (score 8):

## Powershell 19

```
($d|group)[0].Count
```

(this asumes the array is already on `$d`)

Answer (score 8):

## J - 12 char

Anonymous function. Sorts list from most to least common, taking first item.

```
(0{~.\:#/.~)
```

- `0{` First of
- `~.` Unique items
- `\:` Downsorted by
- `#/.~` Frequencies

[Try it for yourself.](http://tryj.tk/)

Comment: This is really 10 bytes--the function can be assigned without the parens.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6) 51

Just a single line expression using the preloaded variable d. Sort the array by frequency then get the first element.
Nasty side effect, the original array is altered

```
d.sort((a,b)=>d.map(w=>t+=(w==b)-(w==a),t=0)&&t)[0]
```

As usual, using .map instead of .reduce because it's 1 char shorter overall. With .reduce it' almost a clean, non-golfed solution.

```
d.sort((a,b)=>d.reduce((t,w)=>t+(w==b)-(w==a),0))[0]
```

At last, a solution using a function, not changing the original array and without globals (62 bytes):

```
F=d=>[...d].sort((a,b)=>d.reduce((t,w)=>t+(w==b)-(w==a),0))[0]
```

**Test** In FireFox/FireBug console

```
d=[4,3,1,0,6,1,6,4,4,0,3,1,7,7,3,4,1,1,2,8]
d.sort((a,b)=>x.map(w=>t+=(w==b)-(w==a),t=0)&&t)[0]
```

*Output* 1

The d array becomes:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 0, 6, 6, 0, 7, 7, 2, 8]
```

Comment: `&&t` => `|t`..

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 21 bytes

```perl6
.Bag.invert.max.value
```

#### Example:

```perl6
$_ = < 4 3 1 0 6 1 6 4 4 0 3 1 7 7 3 4 1 1 2 8 >».Int;

say .Bag.invert.max.value; # implicitly calls $_.Bag…
```

If there is a tie it will print the larger of the ones that tied.

---

The `.Bag` method on a List or an Array creates a quantified hash that associates the total count of how many times a given value was seen with that value.

```perl6
bag(4(4), 3(3), 1(5), 0(2), 6(2), 7(2), 2, 8)
```

The `.invert` method creates a List of the pairs in the bag with the key and the value swapped. ( The reason we call this is for the next method to do what we want )

```perl6
4 => 4,  3 => 3,  5 => 1,  2 => 0,  2 => 6,  2 => 7,  1 => 2,  1 => 8
```

The `.max` method on a List of Pairs returns the biggest Pair comparing the keys first and in the case of a tie comparing the values.
( This is because that is how `multi infix:<cmp>(Pair:D \a, Pair:D \b)` determines which is larger )

```perl6
5 => 1
```

The `.value` method returns the value from the Pair. ( It would have been the key we were after if it wasn't for the `.invert` call earlier )

```perl6
1
```

---

If you want to return all of the values that tied in the case of a tie:

```perl6
say @list.Bag.classify(*.value).max.value».key
```

The `.classify` method returns a list of pairs where the keys are from calling the Whatever lambda `*.value` with each of the Pairs.

```perl6
1 => [2 => 1, 8 => 1],
2 => [0 => 2, 6 => 2, 7 => 2],
3 => [3 => 3],
4 => [4 => 4],
5 => [1 => 5]
```

Then we call `.max` to get the largest Pair.

```perl6
"5" => [1 => 5]
```

A call to `.value` gets us the original Pairs from the Bag ( just one in this case )

```perl6
1 => 5
```

Then we use `>>.key` to call the `.key` method on every Pair in the list, so that we end up with a list of the values that were seen the most.

```perl6
1
```

Answer (score 5):

## Python - 32

```
max((x.count(i),i)for i in x)[1]
```

Don't see an 18 character solution anywhere in the future to be honest.

EDIT: I stand corrected, and impressed.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
.MJ
```

Explanation:

```
.M  # Gets the most frequent element in the [implicit] input
  J # Converts to a string, needed as the program would output "[1]" instead of "1" without this.
```

If you want to store the array in a variable instead of using input, just push the array to the stack at the start of the program.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@6/n6/X/f7SJjrGOoY6BjhmQNNMxAUIDsIg5EBoDeYZAaKRjEfs1L183OTE5IxUA)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, ES6, 71 bytes

A bit long, can be golfed a lot.

```js
f=a=>(c=b=[],a.map(x=>b[x]?b[x]++:b[x]=1),b.map((x,i)=>c[x]=i),c.pop())
```

This creates a function `f` which can be called like `f([1,1,1,2,1,2,3,4,1,5])` and will return `1`.

Try it on your latest Firefox's Console.

Comment: Off-topic, but I just realized how relevant your username is to PCG.SE.  :P

Comment: @nyuszika7h heh. Although I have had this username long before I even know PPCG existed.

Comment: `f=a=>(c=b=[],a.map(x=>b[x]++-1?0:b[x]=1),b.map((x,i)=>c[x]=i),c.pop())` is 1 byte shorter.

Answer (score 4):

## Dyalog APL, 12 characters

[`d[⊃⍒+/∘.=⍨d]`](http://tryapl.org/?a=d%u21904%203%201%200%206%201%206%204%204%200%203%201%207%207%203%204%201%201%202%208%20%u22C4%20d%5B%u2283%u2352+/%u2218.%3D%u2368d%5D&run)

`∘.=⍨d` is the same as `d∘.=d`, reflexive outer product of `=`.  It creates a boolean matrix comparing every pair of elements in `d`.

`+/` sums that matrix along one of the axes and produces a vector.

`⍒` grades the vector, i.e. sorts it by indices.  (As the glyphs suggest, `⍒` grades in descending order and `⍋` would grade in ascending order.)

`⊃` takes the first index from the grading—the index of the largest element of `d`.

`d[...]` returns that element.

Comment: `+/∘.=⍨d` counts for each element of `d`.  `⊢∘≢⌸d` counts for each element of `∪d`, so the indices don't correspond to those of `d`.  Counterexample: `d←1 1 2 2 2`.  To make it work: `(∪d)[⊃⍒⊢∘≢⌸d]` or `(⊃⍒⊢∘≢⌸d)⊃∪d`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
Æṃ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9w28Odzf8PtyscnfRw54z//6NNdIx1DHUMdMyApJmOCRAagEXMgdAYyDMEQiMdi1gA)

Jelly finally got a mode builtin! A non-builtin version however is 5 bytes:

```
ċ@Þ`Ṫ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9It8PheQkPd676f7hd4eikhztn/P8fbaJjrGOoY6BjBiTNdEyA0AAsYg6ExkCeIRAa6VjEAgA)

### How they work

```
Æṃ - Main link. Takes a list d on the left
Æṃ - Return the mode of d
```

Well that was unimpressive. How about the 5 byte, non-builtin version?

```
ċ@Þ`Ṫ - Main link. Takes d on the left
   `  - Use d as both the left and right argument to:
  Þ   -   Sort d by:
ċ@    -     Count occurrences in d
    Ṫ - Take the last element (i.e. the element with a maximal count in d)
```

Answer (score 3):

## C# - 49

Can't really compete using C# but oh well:

Assuming `d` is the array

`d.GroupBy(i=>i).OrderBy(a=>a.Count()).Last().Key;`

Answer (score 3):

## bash - <s>29</s> 27 characters

```
sort|uniq -c|sort -nr|sed q
```

Using it:

```
sort|uniq -c|sort -nr|sed q
4
3
1
0
6
1
6
4
4
0
3
1
7
7
3
4
1
1
2
8
[ctrl-D]
5 1
```

i.e. "1" is the mode, and it appears five times.

Comment: `sort|uniq -c|sort -nr|sed q` saves a couple of characters

Comment: I posted the same answer, but you were faster :)

Comment: @pgy - thank you - have updated!

Answer (score 3):

## GolfScript, 10 bytes

```
a{a\-,}$0=
```

From [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5264/tips-for-golfing-in-golfscript/25737#25737) I wrote to [Tips for golfing in GolfScript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5264/tips-for-golfing-in-golfscript).  Expects the input in an array named `a`, returns result on stack.  (To read input from an array on the stack, prepend `:` for 11 bytes; to read input from stdin (in the format `[1 2 1 3 7]`), also prepend `~` for 12 bytes.)

This code works by iterating over the input array, subtracting each element from the original array, and counting the number of elements left.  This is then used as a key to sort the original array by, and the first element of the sorted array is returned.

[Online demo.](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=IyBUZXN0IGlucHV0IChpbiBhcnJheSBhKToKWzQgMyAxIDAgNiAxIDYgNCA0IDAgMyAxIDcgNyAzIDQgMSAxIDIgOF06YTsKCiMgQ29kZToKYXthXC0sfSQwPQ%3D%3D)

*Ps.* Thanks to Peter Taylor for [pointing out this challenge to me](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19178279#19178279).

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, 83 Bytes

```
d.stream().max((x,y)->Collections.frequency(d,x)-Collections.frequency(d,y)).get();
```

`d` must be a `Collection<Integer>`.

---

If `Collections` can be statically imported:
**59 Bytes**

```
d.stream().max((x,y)->frequency(d,x)-frequency(d,y)).get();
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
ṢŒrṪÞṪṪ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9w56Kjk4oe7lx1eB6QAKL///9Hm@gY6xjqGOiYAUkzHRMgNACLmAOhMZBnCIRGOhaxAA)

Longer than K :(

Assumes the first argument has the array. There are no variables in Jelly.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>42</s> 39 bytes

```hs
f s=snd$maximum[([1|y<-s,y==x],x)|x<-s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02h2LY4L0UlN7EiM7c0N1oj2rCm0ka3WKfS1rYiVqdCs6YCyIv9n5uYmadgq1BQlJlXoqCikKYQbaJjpGOmYwokDXWMgbQZkGUMhEax/wE)

*Edit: Thans to Zgarb for -3 bytes*

Comment: I think `sum` is unnecessary here.

Comment: @Zgarb Right, I actually used exactly the same trick in a [previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144498/56433). Thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 45 bytes

```javascript
x=>x.map(a=t=>a[t]=0+a[t]||[1+t]).sort()[0]-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcjBCoMwEATQ30lwDUkVWyjr0Z8IOSxWSot1xSziwX9Pt@XBDDNv2imP22uVeuHHVAYsB/aH@9BqCAV7ipLQV786zxgqSdZl3sTY6FMdyn3kJfM8uZmfZjCxhQYCeOg0O2iV/z9X1egK6gK3ZG35Ag)

[42](https://tio.run/##FYhBCoMwEEWvk@AYkiq2IuPSS4QsBiulRR0xobjw7nHkwX@8/6M/xXH/bqlc@T3lAfOBfXGYhTZFmLAnnwLa4tZ5ymgTeU9KextyN/IaeZ7MzB81KF9DBQ5aC42ogVqQuL@nUEk64QGvoHW@AA) without 0 support

Answer (score 2):

## Bash + unix tools, 62 bytes

Expects the array in the STDIN. The input format does not count, as long as the numbers are non-negative integers.

```
grep -o [0-9]\*|sort|uniq -c|sort -n|awk 'END{print $2}'
```

Edited: escaped wildcard in grep argument. Now it can be run safely in non-empty directories. Thanks to manatwork.

Comment: Best if run in an empty directory. Otherwise `[0-9]*` may get expanded to matching file names.

Comment: Alternatively, put `'` around the argument to `grep`.

Answer (score 2):

### Java 8 : 184 bytes

```
Stream.of(A).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i, Collectors.counting())).entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder())).findFirst().get().getKey();
```

Input **A** must be of type `Integer[]`. Note `java.util.*` and `java.util.stream.*` need to be imported, however in the spirit oneliner they are left out.

Comment: downvoting because of ... ?

Comment: I know it's been more than two years, but you can remove the spaces at `(i->i,Collectors.counting())`.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell 78

```
import Data.List
import Data.Ord
g=head.maximumBy(comparing length).group.sort
```

If the imports are ignored, it's **45**.

Comment: You can save 4 bytes by using point-free style and 2 bytes by using `maximumBy` instead of `last.sortBy`. The new code would become `g=head.maximumBy(comparing length).group.sort`.

Comment: 1.) Anonymous functions are allowed, so you can drop the `g=`. 2.) You can replace `maximumBy(comparing length)` by `snd.maximum.map((,)=<<length)` which doesn't need to import `Ord`, for a total of 62 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYsxCsMwDEX3nkJDhwSEoEmbKd469gahgyBObGo7xlagt3fEg//@8hzXnw2hNR/zUQTeLEwfX@W2GWd5pZpWivz38Yzq3HXYm3kONu3ietrLcWaqWrbIPoGBXHwSuMMGyxMHnPCl@8BRPekbleHbLg "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 27 bytes

```
$Q[$a{$_}++]=$_ for@F;pop@Q
```

Returns the last most common value in case of a tie.

Answer (score 2):

## jq, 29 characters

```
group_by(.)|max_by(length)[0]
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ jq 'group_by(.)|max_by(length)[0]' <<< '[4,3,1,0,6,1,6,4,4,0,3,1,7,7,3,4,1,1,2,8]'
1
```

[On-line test](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=group_by(.)|max_by(length)[0]&j=[4,3,1,0,6,1,6,4,4,0,3,1,7,7,3,4,1,1,2,8])

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>53</s> 50 bytes

```
<?=array_flip($c=array_count_values($d))[max($c)];
```

Run like this:

```
echo '<?php $d=$argv;?><?=array_flip($c=array_count_values($d))[max($c)]; echo"\n";' | php -- 4 3 1 0 6 1 6 4 4 0 3 1 7 7 3 4 1 1 2 8
```

### Tweaks

- Saved 3 bytes by making use of the freedom to assume the input is assigned to a variable `d`

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 5 bytes

```
ọtᵒth
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3w/@Hu3pKHWyeVZPz/Hx1tomOsY6hjoGMGJM10TIDQACxiDoTGQJ4hEBrpWMTqRINoYx0jIMtCx0LHFIwNgTwj49hYAA)

This isn't really a snippet, but I'm not sure what would be...

```
         The output is
    h    the first element of
   t     the last element of
ọ        a list of [value, number of occurrences] pairs corresponding to
         the input,
  ᵒ      sorted ascending by
 t       their last elements (the numbers of occurrences).
```

Comment: It fails for negative input

Comment: @garg10may Use an underscore instead of a hyphen, it should work that way

Answer (score 2):

### Clojure, 32 bytes

```
#(apply max-key(frequencies %)%)
```

`(frequencies %)` returns a hash-map, which can be used as a function. Given a key it returns the corresponding value :)

Equal length:

```
#(last(sort-by(frequencies %)%))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
.M
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fz/f//2gTHWMdQx0DHTMgaaZjAoQGYBFzIDQG8gyB0EjHIhYA)

Answer (score 2):

## Zsh (builtins only), 55 <s>57</s> <s>62</s> bytes

```sh
for i ({0..9})c=${#${(M)A#$i}}&&((c>d?(d=c,m=i)));<<<$m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@bn5KqoVnNVZpXnFqikKyQopD7Py2/SCFTQaPaQE/PslYz2ValWlmlWsNX01FZJbO2Vk1NQyPZLsVeI8U2WSfXNlNTU9PaxsZGJfd/LZejrYaJgrGCoYKBghmQNFMwAUIDsIg5EBoDeYZAaKRgoWmtALKaBB0KlugQasZ/AA)   <s><sub>[57B](https://tio.run/##lY1BCsIwFET3OcVAPyF/U1JbqsVE6AE8RVKxi1hodWPI2WMUV@7kwcAMzMxzu@aw@ElxFI/bNt3h4BHyZVkxQ0Vd10NiZylWFNWZx4rmlKRUyp08s5TB0iylt@SEMYZCTmK0qkOLBhp90R5dQX@SfaEtrinscOAj3ud/NDD88t3ILw)</sub></s>

No utils like `sort`, `uniq`, `sed`. Uses data from array `A`. The expression `${#${(M)A#$i}}` counts elements of A, matching pattern `$i`. Then we just keep track of the biggest `$c` and matching `$i`. (note, Zsh is triggered by `c>d?...`, just ignore the guff on stderr)

---

[Alternate, regex-ified solution, for 80B](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@bn5KqoVn9Py2/SCFTQaPaQE/PslbTSdtWQ6VawzfLykrTUVkls1aTy8bGRqXaKVqjSBMokaOnUq0MpP0dNJ309e31I2qjDWNr9fTs9TRrY60MrQxr/9dyOdpqmCgYKxgqGCiYAUkzBRMgNACLmAOhMZBnCIRGChaa1gogd5CgQ8ESHULN@A8A).

`B+=(${(Mj::)A#$i})` constructs an array B with all `i`th elements joined, so in the given example the element `11111` is the longest.

```bash
for i ({0..9})B+=(${(Mj::)A#$i})
<<<${B[(r)${(l.${#${(O@)B//?/X}[1]}..?.)}]:1:1}
```

<sub>Sample code taken from the Zsh User Guide. [Quote](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide05.html): *"This chapter will appeal above all to people who are excited by the fact that `print ${array[(r)${(l.${#${(O@)array//?/X}[1]}..?.)}]` prints out the longest element of the array `$array` [...] This is for advanced students only (nutcases, if you ask me)."*

PS: Here's a slightly [more sensible way](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@bn5KqoVn9Py2/SCFTQaPaQE/PslbTSdtWQ6VawzfLykrTUVkls1aTC6SgWEFDxUlTQ0NFOddGRblYU1NNLddWpZjLxsZGJTfaMPZ/LZejrYaJgrGCoYKBghmQNFMwAUIDsIg5EBoDeYZAaKRgoWmtALKcBB0KlugQasZ/AA) for 69B</sub>

Answer (score 2):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 32 bytes

```
$=>[m:maximum tally&[k,v][v]m\0]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?mMnDbY)

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>39</s> 37 bytes

```julia
~d=argmax(@.sum(==(1:max(d...)),[d]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/vy7FNrEoPTexQsNBr7g0V8PWVsPQCsRN0dPT09TUiU6J1dT8n6JgqxBtomOsY6hjoGMGJM10TIDQACxiDoTGQJ4hEBrpWMRyOSQWF6cWlSjUAbXZKhj@BwA)

The solution above works for positive integers. It can be adapted to handle `0`:

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>41</s> 39 bytes

```julia
~d=argmax(@.sum(==(0:max(d...)),[d]))-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/vy7FNrEoPTexQsNBr7g0V8PWVsPACsRN0dPT09TUiU6J1dTUNfyfomCrEG2iY6xjqGOgYwYkzXRMgNAALGIOhMZAniEQGulYxHI5JBYXpxaVKNQBtdkqGHIhBKINgHoMYkHCBv8B)

-2 bytes thanks to MarcMush: use `sum` instead of `count`

Comment: This won't work if zero is the most common element

Comment: Great catch! I added a solution for all nonnegative inputs. Since the prompt only mentions positive integers and gives no example with mode 0, I'll also include the original solution.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-h`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 5 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ü ñÊÌ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=/CDxysw&input=WzQsMywxLDAsNiwxLDYsNCw0LDAsMywxLDcsNywzLDQsMSwxLDIsOF0)

```
ñ@è¶X
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=8UDotlg&input=WzQsMywxLDAsNiwxLDYsNCw0LDAsMywxLDcsNywzLDQsMSwxLDIsOF0)

```
ü ñÊÌ     :Implicit input of array
ü         :Group & sort
  ñ       :Sort by
   Ê      :  Length
    Ì     :Last element
          :Implicit output of last element
```

```
ñ@è¶X     :Implicit input of array
ñ         :Sort by
 @        :Passing each X through the following function
  è       :  Count the elements in U
   ¶X     :    Equal to X
          :Implicit output of last element
```

Comment: It sucks that Japt doesn't have a occurences builtin and than you have to use `è¶`

Answer (score 2):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 2 bytes

```
ŢṂ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHHBgqWlJWm6FkuPLnq4s2lJcVJyMVRkwU3NaBMdYx1DHQMdMyBppmMChAZgEXMgNAbyDIHQSMciFqIDAA)

```
Ţ   Tally
 Ṃ  Maximum by
```

Let's take the input `[4,3,1,0,6,1,6,4,4,0,3,1,7,7,3,4,1,1,2,8]` as an example.

`Ţ` returns two lists `[4,3,1,0,6,7,2,8]` and `[4,3,5,2,2,2,1,1]`, where the first list contains the unique elements of the input, and the second list contains the number of occurrences of each element.

`Ṃ` finds an element in the first list with the largest corresponding element in the second list, and returns that element. In this case, the maximum of the second list is `5`, and the corresponding element in the first list is `1`, so `Ṃ` returns `1`.

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 32

```
d.groupBy(a=>a).maxBy(_._2.size)
```

Answer (score 1):

### C++ 119

```
int *a=std::max_element(x,x+n);int z=0,b=0,c=0;for(int i=0;i<=*a;i++){c=std::count(x,x+n,i);if(c>b){b=c;z=i;}}return z;
```

Full code and test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int m(int *x,int n)
{
int *a=std::max_element(x,x+n);int z=0,b=0,c=0;for(int i=0;i<=*a;i++){c=std::count(x,x+n,i);if(c>b){b=c;z=i;}}return z;
}

int main()
{
int d[] = {4,3,1,0,6,1,6,4,4,0,3,1,7,7,3,4,1,1,2,8};
std::cout<<m(d,20);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Ceylon, 67

```ceylon
E m<E>(E+l)=>(l.frequencies().max(increasingItem)else nothing).key;
```

This function works on any type of element, including Integers (though `null` elements are ignored). (And it is shorter than the same function for just integers.)

Formatted:

```ceylon
E m<E>(E+ l) =>
        (l
        .frequencies()
        .max(increasingItem)
            else nothing)
    .key;
```

The `else nothing` is needed, because the Ceylon compiler can't figure out that `l.frequencies` always is non-empty if `l` is nonempty (because in general, all elements of `l` could be `null`, and therefore discarded).

You can call this function like this:

```ceylon
print(m(4,3,1,0,6,1,6,4,4,0,3,1,7,7,3,4,1,1,2,8));
```

If you already have a list `list`, call it like this:

```ceylon
print(m(*list));
```

(This will unpack the list into arguments, and pass them to the function.)

Answer (score 1):

## [Hassium](http://HassiumLang.com), 94 Bytes

This example assumes that the array is stored in `d`

```
func main(){t,b=0;foreach(e in d){c=0;foreach(n in d)if(e==n)c++;if(c>b){b=c;t=e;}}println(t)}
```

See expanded and run online with test case [here](http://ttp://HassiumLang.com/Hassium/index.php?code=f87fe7f18e4a79cb0ca91769b953ac9f)

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 10 bytes

```
D3m/DSe@R@
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=D3m%2FDSe%40R%40&input=%5B1%2C1%2C2%2C2%2C3%5D)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 11 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 9.05 bytes

```
ztcZZz;AJAK
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuharq0qSo6KqrB29HL0hIlCJBTc1o010jHUMdQx0zICkmY4JEBqARcyB0BjIMwRCIx2LWIgOAA)

Thunno doesn't have a `mode` built-in so we have to implement it ourselves:

```python
ztcZZz;AJAK  # Implicit input
zt           # Triplicate the (implicit) input
  c          # And get the count of each element
   ZZ        # Zip with the input
             # So we have a nested list of the form
             # [[count, element], [count, element], ...]
     z;      # And reverse-sort this list of lists
             # (so the first pair will be the mode)
       AJ    # Get the first pair
         AK  # And get the last item
             # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 5 bytes (10 nibbles)

```
/+=~$,+`%@
```

```
  =~        # group and sort
    $       # the input
            # by
     ,      #   length of
      +     #   flattened
       `%   #   split
         @  #   the input
            #   by
            #   (implicitly) each element  
 +          # then flatten this
/           # and output the first element 
            # (by folding over list returning left-hand
            # argument at each step)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 1 [byte](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Ṁ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMSVCOSU4MCZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PTQlMkMzJTJDMSUyQzAlMkM2JTJDMSUyQzYlMkM0JTJDNCUyQzAlMkMzJTJDMSUyQzclMkM3JTJDMyUyQzQlMkMxJTJDMSUyQzIlMkM4JmZsYWdzPQ==)

Built-in.