# Most common elements of a list in Python

Tags: code-golf, tips, python

<sup>*This is a tips question for golfing in Python, which is on topic for main.*</sup>

I'm looking for the shortest way to get all of the most common elements of a list in Python, in the shortest way possible. Here's what I've tried, assuming the list is in a variable called `l`:

```python
from statistics import*
mode(l)
```

This throws an error if there are multiple modes.

```python
max(l,key=l.count)
```

This only returns 1 item, I need to get *all* the elements of greatest count.

```python
from collections import*
Counter(l).most_common()
```

This returns a list of tuples of `(element, count)`, sorted by count. From this I could pull all the elements whose corresponding count is equal to the first, but I don't see a way to golf this much better than:

```python
from collections import*
c=Counter(l).most_common()
[s for s,i in c if i==c[0][1]]
```

I am sure there is a shorter way!

Also, if it can be done without variable assignment or multiple uses of `l`, I can keep the rest of the code as a lambda expression to save more bytes.

Edit: Per @Uriel's suggestion, we can do:

```python
{s for s in l if l.count(s)==l.count(max(l,key=l.count))}
```

And I can alias `list.count` for a few bytes:

```python
c=l.count;{s for s in l if c(s)==c(max(l,key=c))}
```

@Uriel pointed out that we can get a couple more bytes with `map`:

```python
c=l.count;{s for s in l if c(s)==max(map(c,l))}
```

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/42529/69054), but doesn't do what I need

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this one?

```py
c=l.count;{x for x in l if c(x)==max(map(c,l))}
```

Enclose in `[*...]` to get a list.

Comment: Oh right, I do need a unique list or set, thanks

Comment: @musicman523 why did you update with `l.count(max(l,key=l.count))`? `max(map(l.count,l))` is shorter

Comment: Ahhhh I didn't think of that one, thank you!