# Special String reformatting

Tags: code-golf, string

This challenge is to take an alphabetical string as input and to apply the following conversion:

The first of each type of character of the string must stay, and must be immediately followed by an integer representing how many of these characters were in the original string. Any repeating characters must be omitted.

All inputs will be entirely lower-case letters (no spaces). Outputs must be ordered in the same way as the inputs (input `hi` must give output of `h1i1`, not `i1h1`)

## Examples

Input: `potato` Output: `p1o2t2a1`

Input: `pqwertyuiop` Output: `p2q1w1e1r1t1y1u1i1o1`

Input: `thisisanexample` Output: `t1h1i2s2a2n1e2x1m1p1l1`

Input: `oreganoesque` Output: `o2r1e3g1a1n1s1q1u1`

Input: `aaaaaaabaaaaaa` Output: `a13b1`

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest answer wins!

Comment: Since the input cannot have spaces, can we separate the letters and the digits with spaces?

Comment: @Adám I'm going to say no just so the output format stays consistent and unchangeable

Comment: Could we output in pairs (i.e. `["p1","o2","t2","a1"]` instead of `p1o2t2a1`)?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I'm going to say no so that the output stays consistent for all answers, but feel free to add it as an aside to your answer because now I'm curious as to how much shorter this could make your code

Comment: Lowercase letters, or lower case ASCII? Your example only contains ASCII.

Comment: @Abigail lower case ASCII, if that's what my example uses. Sorry, I didn't realise there was a difference

Comment: Suggested test case: `abaaacaaaaaaa` (more than 9 of the same letter).

Comment: @Zgarb good idea, I edited it into the question

Comment: @Sqepia There are 26 lowercase ASCII letters, but there are over 2000 lower case letters in Unicode. `perl -E 'for (1 .. 0x10FFFF) {$c ++ if chr ($_) =~ /\p{Lower}/} say $c'` for a quick count (it's a bit of a moving target, as each revision of the Unicode standard may introduce more lower case characters).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shorten text with Run Length Encoding](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7320/shorten-text-with-run-length-encoding)

Comment: @pppery I guess this is similar, but this question doesn't allow for duplicate characters at all. This question was really a test to see how fast challenges would be solved - my next challenge (in a few days) will be more creative and harder to solve

Comment: Easy challenges get answered quickly. Hard challenges ... not so much

Comment: @pppery I figured. This is my first challenge I've posted here after years of lurking (so I wanted to make something relatively simple to see how many answers I would get), I'm gonna try to make some really good challenges soon

Comment: @pppery I don't think it's a duplicate, although it's close. That challenge asks to read all lines and to output the run-length encoding, whereas this one has a single input and outputs the uniquified run-length encoding (i.e. `test` would result in `t1e1s1t1` in that other challenge, but `t2e1s1` here). They're definitely closely related, but not a dupe imo.

Answer (score 10):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 7 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319) ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

Anonymous tacit prefix function.

```apl
,,∘⍕∘≢⌸
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///X0fnUceMR71TQWTnokc9O/6nPWqb8Ki371FX86PeNY96txxab/yobeKjvqnBQc5AMsTDM/h/mnpBfkliSb46F5BVWJ5aVFJZmplfAOKWZGQWZxYn5qVWJOYW5KSChPKLUtMT8/JTiwtLU9UB)

`⌸` apply the following function between each unique character and the indices where it occurs:

`,` concatenate the character

`∘` to

`⍕` the stringification

`∘` of

`≢` the indices' count

`,` flatten

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>58</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>50</s></sup> 57 bytes

Added 3 bytes and switched to Python 3 to fix bugs.
Added 7 bytes to make output a string.

```python
lambda s:''.join(c+f'{s.count(c)}'for c in{}.fromkeys(s))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NZDRbsIwDEXf@xURL2k0huR00iSk7keAh1BcyNbGaZwKKsS3d2kq8uLca9lXx36KN3LV3NbHuTP9@WIE76Xc/ZJ1ZfPRyifvGhpdLBv1ki0F0Qjrnq9dG6j/w4lLVmqOyJFFLQ4bT9FE2mzFxg93DHEaLflFxptly8bhw/S@w8WigFfjCHkYszbrO68lOacCHx6biJd1N5CO2kDerge4A0KACBOMYIGyH@EGVrM22gHqB/Tgocsd0gGwuoIBBwxDmsmZUJ0hR4WUUY7yOOrvr0ZuxfqFSqpiwbYJWwTjrlh26MpMrNS@EAt3u@qDPalC@GDTud5GyhCfPyJF8FaEwxsodeqaT2r@Bw)

Outputs a string.

Outputting a list of strings is [50 bytes](https://tio.run/##NZDBjoMgEIbvPgXpBcl2mwxuskkT90WsB7Rjy64CMphqmj67i5hygfkmzJ9v3BLu1hRrV17WXg3NVTE6V@1Hx590au1kQt6KF@@sZy3T5vk6dd4Of7hQTqJeA1IgVrLq4GxQwR6O7ODGB/qwTNq6rQx3TZqUwVkNrscNWY83ZSzSOKVa7afZr0jqDGeHbcDrPhusDFJBmi5HeACChwALTKDBJh7gDlqSVNIAyhkGcNCnjpUesLiBAgMEY/yTMqFoIEX5mJFP/DLJ76@WH9n@hIKLbNPWUZt5ZW6Y92jyZCzEOWObN@enX6tN3u280rUQGXNex729SQxjnz8sZtGR@eptFjtlSbVY/wE).

Comment: Using a dict is a really nice idea! It can be 2 bytes shorter with `dict(zip(s,s))`.

Comment: @ovs Thanks! Just saved 3 bytes using `{}` instead of `dict` :-)

Answer (score 5):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 63 bytes

```php
foreach(array_count_values(str_split($argn))as$a=>$b)echo$a.$b;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY07DsIwEAV7n4LCRVLABcKnAlEgkRtYm2iJLQXvxrsGcnlMUF4xM91jz2V/4oUPSgi9ryAlmF1POap7wZhRKtHkhMeglYU0xLoGsXA42q7G3pOFne2a8s9Ne23d@X5rCpOCkuHpjUnnHIiN@iBBIOIHnjyiWf4GiIQyZTSwrlv1JdZAUcr28gM)

Built-ins and a whole lot of glue.  Input via `STDIN`, output to `STDOUT`.

Comment: too bad `count_chars` doesn't return an array ordered as the string

Comment: A more interesting version is `array_walk(array_count_values(str_split($argn)),fn($a,$b)=>print($b.$a));`. Sadly, it's 72 bytes long... :(

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel why would it be more interesting? it's basically the same with a callback overhead, longer, less performant.. just my opinion ;) A little advice, `print` doesn't need brackets: `array_walk(array_count_values(str_split($argn)),fn($a,$b)=>print$b.$a);` would do

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I like the functional concept of that approach and it's too bad you can't do some variant like `array_walk(array_count_values(str_split($argn)),print);` (55 bytes) but that won't work sadly.

Comment: @Kaddath Yes, a plain boring old loop sure is more **interesting** than implementing new concepts added in the latest versions of PHP .... (Yes, it's faster, but ...)

Comment: @640KB That would be amazing. Oh, something to try is the removed `split` function, which I couldn't get to work, but may save some bytes... Or none...

Comment: Well, the closest I got is `array_walk(array_count_values(str_split($argn)),'printf');` but it doesn't print out the 2nd parameter... :(

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 34 bytes

This is the dreaded *obvious chain-the-built-ins*. `Print` can accept multiple arguments and will print them without any separators.

```
Print@@Flatten@Tally@Characters@#&
```

More scary version, for the same number of bytes:

```
Print@@(##&)@@@Tally@Characters@#&
```

I suspect that a better hack consisting entirely of the characters `#&/()` can be used to get rid of Flatten, but I couldn't come up with one.

Of course, Mathematica has both `LetterCounts` *and* `CharacterCounts`, and there's also `Counts` instead of `Tally`, but all of these seem to return association objects that seem excessively complicated to work with.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcY7CoAwEAXA3mNE8BbCgpDawk5TPGQhgfxIXqGnj041CfSawHBj2PUaewuZIjaC1CwHYnxl82i4qa3LvAx7mloIFuOm//Shh46sD1KNatz4AA)

Comment: `Association` objects can be converted to lists of `Rule`s using `Normal`, but the `Rule` objects end up taking more bytes to work with.

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>15</s> 17 bytes

Thanks to Jonah for finding and fixing a bug!

```
[:;~.<@,&":"0#/.~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/BisJADIbvPkWo4CBo13@8zSoIgqc9ed1TXKKdRZtpZ4p68dW7grbCGgjhD99HyG@b5WZPS0eGJjQjd@9pTuvt16b9dp@3fLGajDKXzYYf@a0dDwbyUyjtyQRNnNT0mR@1e4zn3gSoTZZhaOreLBNshTMENRKuaOChL7I6S52ujdfQ4QkFvI2WbQmxF5wQcOyFVPjoI5dy4VM4SieprSHzAxglIqr7lU7QWg5cqsSq6WnGfNcD/15q/wA)

Comment: `~.,@,.":@#/.~` is equivalent for 13 bytes, but both yours and the 13 byte version fail the final test case.  This [rather verbose 19 byte version](https://tio.run/##bY1BasNADEX3OYVIF6JgT/InO0MhUOiqq95ACUo8JbHGnjFJNr66EzB2NxV8PkLvod9x7fhEHxUxFbSl6pXS0efP99fIxKUbBlfsC7eu9m8bN4zvq5Uea6MTcbQs2XjaOcJ89gKmsvrn6lvcoOiQ8UCPAPsj25t2@dEHizOeUSP45MU3UH/HFRGXRch1SCFJo3e5xovOkvkOujtD0CChfX2ZBev0LI1pavuFFuwOCyDTHKbi8Qk "J – Try It Online") passes all test cases.

Comment: [17 bytes passing all test cases](https://tio.run/##ZY/BisJADIbvPkWo4CBo13@8zSoIgqc9ed1TXKKdRZtpZ4p68dW7grbCGgjhD99HyG@b5WZPS0eGJjQjd@9pTuvt16b9dp@3fLGajDKXzYYf@a0dDwbyUyjtyQRNnNT0mR@1e4zn3gSoTZZhaOreLBNshTMENRKuaOChL7I6S52ujdfQ4QkFvI2WbQmxF5wQcOyFVPjoI5dy4VM4SieprSHzAxglIqr7lU7QWg5cqsSq6WnGfNcD/15q/wA "J – Try It Online")

Comment: @Jonah Thanks! I think the last test case was added later and I didn't revisit my J solution.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 49 bytes

```python
lambda s:''.join({c+str(s.count(c)):1for c in s})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDRasMwDEXf/RWmL4lZV5AzGBTSH2n74KZq65HajqXQhLFvzxyHQje9WLrCutwTRr55V02X@jC15n46G0nboth8eevK7@aNOJa0aXzvuGyU2sLFR9lI6yT9qImRmGQt96vg2bBfreUqdA@MPPbWh3nkmyVLxuFg7qHFWfIRr8Z5pK7Ps1nqtDxJOQocAjaM5@U2eM3aQL6uO3gAQgSGEXqw4LPOcAOrSRvtAPUAdwjQ5o3XEbC6ggEHBF36kz2hOkG2ismj7ItDrz8/mmItlxaqQok5q52zRuOuWLboypw4cRByzv0EdVn0vT0qJWSINtF6KslMvu9k8qK1jPtnsrSpazqqaSEnXrCJf8zEKzDxl9Yv)

Outputs a string.

Based on [Noodle9's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205837/20260), which uses a nice idea of a dictionary to deduplicate while preserving order, which they do in Python 3 but not Python 2. Note that `set` doesn't preserve order.

The idea is to make the character-with-count strings be keys of a dictionary so that only the first instance is used. The values in the dictionary don't matter, since dictionaries iterate over keys by default.

I had thought at first that the deduplication must be applied to the characters of the input string, but realized that it also works on the strings to be joined in the output, since a given character is always attached to the same count.

Outputting a list of strings without joining takes [43 bytes](https://tio.run/##XZDRasMwDEXf/RWmL0m2riBnMChkP5LmwU3V1iO1HUuhCWPfnjkOhW56sXSFdbnHT3x1tpzP1WHu9O140pL29ct3@0occtq1brCct0Wxh7MLspXGSvppZkZikpWsN96xZrfZyo3v7xh4Gozzy8hXQ4a0xVHffIeL5AJetHVI/ZBmvdZxfaLSCBw9toyn9TY4xUpDuq56uANCAIYJBjDgks5wBaNIaWUB1Qg38NCljVMBsLyABgsEffyTPKE8QrIK0SMfssOgPt7bbCvXFsqsEEtWs2QN2l4w79DmKXHkIOSSO8t2X87Y/LzqtWmKQkgfTKT1UKKZfPuU0Yu2MtSPZHFTVdQU80pOPGET/5iJZ2DiL61f).

Answer (score 4):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>23</s> 18  bytes

```
{,/t,'$+/x=\:t:?x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYjRCkAwFED/ZSmEvE/yI16uuljDHbvLJN8@tPNyOkdXpEMY5V3WXKZJUfu2lyw7/4QxzYQhBibRCLOfePDlFJmveFZWWdjQw2oW/A4dOMFGaHf3J0SGKJGHFw)

Comment: `,/(!g),'$.g:#:'=` for **16 bytes**

Comment: @streetster In which verson of K? I can't make it work in oK in TIO

Comment: oK - https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/X0dfQzFdU0ddRS/dStlK3VapoLA8taiksjQzv0Dp/38A

Comment: @streetster Oh, I was trying to run it in a list of strings (as in my solution)

Comment: Ah, then yours is shorter if we need to define as a function :)

Comment: Managed a 17 byte (function) with K4, `f:{,/(?x),'.$#:'=x}` but it works because the `$` is applied to the value of the dictionary, not the whole thing.

Comment: @streetster I always define my answers as functions. Anyway, thank you for your solutions - I need to lear how to work with dictionaries.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Ùε¢yì?
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8MxzWw8tqjy8xv7//4L8ksSS/P@6unn5ujmJVZUA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##AWYAmf9vc2FiaWX/fHZ5PyIg4oaSICI/ecKp/8OZzrXCrnPConnDrD//fcK2P/9oaQpwb3RhdG8KcHF3ZXJ0eXVpb3AKdGhpc2lzYW5leGFtcGxlCm9yZWdhbm9lc3F1Zf8tLW5vLWxhenk).

**Explanation:**

```python
Ù       # Uniquify the (implicit) input-string
 ε      # For-each over each character in this string:
  ¢     #  Count the amount of times the current character occurs in the (implicit) input
   yì   #  Prepend the current character before this count
     ?  #  Print it without newline
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Lƙż@Q
```

A full program printing the result (or a monadic Link yielding a list of pairs of characters and integers).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/n2MyjexwC////X5KRWZxZnJiXWpGYW5CTCgA)**

There are loads of ways to achieve this in 6 bytes (e.g. `Qżċ@€¥`).

#### How?

```
Lƙż@Q - Main Link: list of characters, S          e.g. "cabbage"
 ƙ    - for groups of identical elements (of S):       (c aa bb g e)
L     -   length                                       [1,2,2,1,1]
    Q - de-duplicate S                                 "cabge"
   @  - with swapped arguments:
  ż   -   zip                                          [['c',1],['a',2],['b',2],['g',1],['e',1]]
      - implicit, smashing, print                      c1a2b2g1e1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 62 bytes

```python
f=lambda s:s and s[0]+str(s.count(s[0]))+f(s.replace(s[0],''))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcpLCoAgEADQq7jTwYigXdBJosXkhwJTcaZFpzdt@3j55TPFuVa/BrwPi4IWEhitoG3aNXFRNJr0RFYdALRvUFwOaNxPg5QANZerFa9kToycOn0)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 55 bytes

```javascript
s=>[...new Set(s)].map(c=>c+~-s.split(c).length).join``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc2xbsJAEATQPl9hUdmKODRHbX4iJYrE4iz2ofPt@W4dQ5Nfd0xIUsA008zTnOmTcpNc1HWQD55P9Zzr3d4YE3gq3ljLXL2bnmLZ1Lvm9WudTY7eadlUxnNotavMWVw4HOZGQhbPxktbnspVFCWVVVUV/9lsigixagkvj@th4qTX0Un8I7e1HTCBkaC4YoSDPEntXHaZAl@oj55vepGKDs5mSzaA7QU9IvyTlcQtBeE8jPx7u1ixCbxtQQjIGJbfR0f3HO/1IxdH2B4xfwM)

#### Commented

```javascript
s =>                    // s = input string
  [...new Set(s)]       // create a set from the input string and split it,
                        // resulting in an array of characters arranged in
                        // order of first appearance
  .map(c =>             // for each character c in this array:
    c +                 //   append c
    ~-s.split(c).length //   followed by the number of occurrences in the
                        //   original string
  )                     // end of map()
  .join``               // join everything
```

Answer (score 2):

## perl -p, <strike>52</strike> 50 bytes

```
s/./$&1/g;1while s/(\D)\K(\d+)(.*)\1\d/($2+1).$3/e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcGxDsIgEADQna9wIA3YyAWNU1c3f4GFpJeWBLkrR1P9eel7jDU/exdwoAcPy@SPNWW8CJjwsuFtwjxa4642@DCD0ffRW6cfgL0ztdhI8XZgbb89Eau2JkkSC37jhzMqqrjEQijbjn/ilqhIv/EJ)

Starts off by adding 1 to each character. Then, as often as possible, find a letter followed by a number, with the same letter elsewhere in the string followed by a digit (which has to be 1). Increment the count, and remove the same letters followed by its 1.

Initial solution, following a very different technique:

## perl -nF//, 52 bytes

```
$F{$_}++for@F;$F{$_}&&print$_,$F{$_}xor$F{$_}=0for@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5Ba8JQEITv@RWDBi9W0h48BcHTOxd6rCKvsNGFuLu@tyGWYn96U2Ogh85phhn4xii168HUsA3gBmXA@@plj803qp1UNYA53jyxQRsI9S0LjUMW6xynmME@lOGrPNyWy0bTNtRTWiwssXh5eJryVdNkNs@P2VA/@tlOZiPln@Z4HVvEP@YHeU8k0M7v5Hz/7NG1sEtPyT87Viv8xJlzFLrGs7VUaKJjFKV86ehHzVklDysJVfUL)

Reads a line from `STDIN`, assuming it's **not** newline terminated.

Splits the input into characters, available (in order), in `@F` (due to the `-F//`). Counts the occurrence of each character in the hash `%F`. Then loops over `@F`: if present in `%F` with a true value, print the character and its count, then set the corresponding entry in `%F` to 0. This ensures each character is only outputted once.

The TIO code has some header and footer code so we can handle multiple test inputs. They're not needed if we just have one line of input.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>105</s> \$\cdots\$<s>93</s></sup> 90 bytes

Saved <s>2</s> 5 bytes from the man himself [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)!!!

```c
d;c;f(char*s){for(;d=1,c=*s;c-1&&printf("%c%d",c,d))for(char*q=s++;*++q;d+=*q==c?*q=1:0);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZHRboIwFIbvfYqGRFMEEk6NF1vHdrHsKcSLWgpilJa2RIzx1ccKqGPZSdrmnP5f/uYvjwrOuy6jnOaY75leGv@aS41plkDIk6WhPILFQumysjn25nyeeSEPM9/vVQNRJyYI6DIIapoFiWsT/uF2eI19eutOrKywj64z5GrQI73ZogRdvbT9Imn78unW2gvRtF95NzohrDDW3CklLbOy16v6LLS9NKVUfWv3pSkNq0TLTuoo@pHUomCVFKZuhp6NtRuPvx6iVaK1Ihtseh@QxBIGgxOp4QwCNFi4QAMlyGFuYQ8lMYSRCgRp4QQKjsONJBrEqgAGFRioHTP4w2oHU1u0a/Jc6A3Ecbwdxy5XhF3a6ODeEVN3vKE1RUFweKTYl7Gaqwse8fAe0GHr06fi8WWpNzeph6J3lHruDSMx0eX43@gXRXjE/bRy7DOip9Ftduu@eX5khemi8w8)

Comment: [93 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZZHRaoMwFIbv@xRBaNGq4EnpxZa5XYw9hXqRxtgqrdEkUkvx2V2MXefYgXA4f87PF/6w8MjYOFYkJ4wULjtRuVXevRDSJSzeKt8nLITNppFlrQvXWbN17gQsCHPPm5byuIpDICrx/SojeRirpMrimH3YDq@RR4bxQsva9dB9hUxZBJJJhmJ0d9L@C6f9y6c5eydAy3nnDGTh0Fxp9XA1QlMtpv2mvXKpb10pmmnUp1KVita8p5fmzCdJSH6kteCq7exM5zrM7S@D9w3vNc8tZuKAwBpTsCTcwhU4SNBwgw5KEFbXcIISK0xxDRz3cIEGzvZGYAl8dwQKNShojcfyYXeAJRYduqLgMoEoirJZNski1wSOKvOOiJj2hvYEmYx/UpxKacmamzvbg0dAVeaR58bPr6XOWqUOCt9R6pg3zI7FXuH@k36tyJ3tXlob7zOiJ2hYDeM3)

Comment: @Arnauld Diabolical, was trying to align `j` and `d` and clean up the string access with no joy - thanks! :D

Comment: Using a 2nd pointer is actually shorter: [90 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZZHRboIwFIbvfYqGRFMEEk6NF1vHdrHsKcSLWgpilJa2RIzx1ccKqGPZSdrmnP5f/uYvjwrOuy6jnOaY75leGv@aS41plkDIk6WhPILFQumysjn25nyeeSEPM9/vVQNRJyYI6DIIapoFiWsT/uF2eI19eutOrKywj64z5GrQI73ZogRdvbT9Imn78unW2gvRtF95NzohrDDW3CklLbOy16v6LLS9NKVUfWv3pSkNq0TLTuoo@pHUomCVFKZuhp6NtRuPvx6iVaK1Ihtseh@QxBIGgxOp4QwCNFi4QAMlyGFuYQ8lMYSRCgRp4QQKjsONJBrEqgAGFRioHTP4w2oHU1u0a/Jc6A3Ecbwdxy5XhF3a6ODeEVN3vKE1RUFweKTYl7Gaqwse8fAe0GHr06fi8WWpNzeph6J3lHruDSMx0eX43@gXRXjE/bRy7DOip9Ftduu@eX5khemi8w8)

Comment: @Arnauld Interesting, the thought crossed my mind but dismissed it right away - thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 5 bytes

```
ọ∋∋w⊥
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6OmpkcdKx7u2vFwV2ftw60T/j/c3fuooxuIyh91Lf3/P1qpIL8ksSRfSUepoLA8taiksjQzvwDIK8nILM4sTsxLrUjMLchJBYrkF6WmJ@blpxYXloK4iRCQBKGUYgE)

Full program, or alternatively a predicate which prints the output then fails. Could be [one byte shorter](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6OmpofbFjzc1Vn7cOuE/w939z7q6Iag//@jlQrySxJL8pV0lAoKy1OLSipLM/MLgLySjMzizOLEvNSKxNyCnFSgSH5RanpiXn5qcWEpiJsIAUkQSikWAA) if it could generate the characters as a mix of strings and integers, but that seems like a bit too far out there of an output format.

```
   w     Print (without a newline)
  ∋      an element of
 ∋       an element of
ọ        a list of pairs [element, # of occurrences] in order of first appearance,
    ⊥    then try it again some other way.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) + `-F ''`, 65 + 4 = 69 bytes

```
{while(i++<NF)if(!a[$i]++)b[i]=$i;while(j++<i)printf b[j]a[b[j]]}
```

[Try it at awk.js.org](https://awk.js.org/index.html?gist=ac8b7f486b4843f801f434197914da9d)

A shorter <s>64</s> 59+4 byte program, which runs on GNU awk with `-F ''`, is this:

```
{while(i++<NF)if(!a[$i]++)b[i]=1;for(i in b)printf$i a[$i]}
```

Annoyingly, though, while 'Try it online' links to the GNU awk manual page, it doesn't seem to use GNU awk, and refuses the `-F ''` command-line option.

The alternative link above (to awk .js.org) accepts the command-line option, but then outputs in a different order, which costs a frustrating additional <s>one</s> six bytes  to correct (which I have included above as the price of verifiability).

Comment: we don't count flags as part of byte count any longer; instead, the flags used count as part of a separate language as opposed to just AWK.

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 12 bytes

Port of the Pyth answer.

```
q:A_&{_Ae=}%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v9DKMV6tOt4x1bZW9f//gvySxJJ8AA)

### Explanation

```
q            Take the whole input
 :A          Assign to a variable
   _&        Set union w/ itself
     {    }% Map:
      _          Join the uniquified character
       Ae=       With the count of the character in the input string.
```

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 16 bytes

CJam has the built-in, so I guess it simplifies the question. Unfortunately the built-in does it in the wrong order...

```
q:A{A#}$e`{-1%}%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v9DKsdpRuVYlNaFa11C1VvX//4L8ksSSfAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 28 bytes

```perl
s|.|($b=s/$&//g)?$&.$b:''|ge
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@4Rq9GQyXJtlhfRU1fP13TXkVNTyXJSl29Jj31//9ECEiCUP/yC0oy8/OK/@sWAAA)

Comment: Nice one! Nested `s///` feels like it shouldn't work!

Comment: @DomHastings  I don't disagree.  However, if it's stupid but works... :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby 2.7](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/25/ruby-2-7-0-released/) -paF|, 17 bytes

```
$_=[*$F.tally]*''
```

[Try it online!](https://techiedelight.com/compiler/ruby?CpL5)

This is more or less built in to the recent Ruby release as the `tally` method.

Answer (score 2):

## [K4](https://kx.com/download/) <s>17</s> 16 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{,/(?x),'$#:'=x}
```

**Examples:**

```
q)k){,/(?x),'$#:'=x}"potato"
"p1o2t2a1"
q)k){,/(?x),'$#:'=x}"pqwertyuiop"
"p2q1w1e1r1t1y1u1i1o1"
q)k){,/(?x),'$#:'=x}"thisisanexample"
"t1h1i2s2a2n1e2x1m1p1l1"
q)k){,/(?x),'$#:'=x}"oreganoesque"
"o2r1e3g1a1n1s1q1u1"
q)k){,/(?x),'$#:'=x}"aaaaaaabaaaaaa"
"a13b1"
```

**Explanation:**

```
{,/(?x),'$#:'=x} / the solution
{              } / lambda function taking implicit 'x' argument
             =x  / group x (dict of unique chars => indices)
          #:'    / count length of each group
         $       / cast to string
       ,'        / join each-both
   (  )          / do this together
    ?x           / distinct x
 ,/              / flatten
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>72</s> 71 bytes

```r
cat(rbind(z<-unique(y<-el(strsplit(scan(,""),""))),table(y)[z]),sep="")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcoxDoAgDEDRuzC1CdwAT2IcCjKQEEBaBrl8xeEvL3@oRhIYIdcblnez5mcmeL1LBVgG95IFOFIFawz@IVqhUPaE57rQcurHZu1NSJp@)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), <s>106</s> 102 bytes

```javascript
e=>{for(o="",i=0;i<e.length;i++)o.includes(e[i])||(o+=e[i]+e.match(RegExp(e[i],"g")).length);return o}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzBCgIhFEV/JVwpTtIyMNv1A22jhdjTMcwn@mYImr7dpmh34Zxz73a2zdVYaDvvuzcdzPHlsXI0jA3R7HQ8gEqQA406SilQxezSdIPG4RKvYlk4SvOdEtTDkhv5GcLpWX54YIEJ8e@FrkBTzRt8d4e5YVqfMXDPWUGyhKvaPw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 9 bytes

```
u$:@$C¦Z$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/v1TFykHF@dCyKJX//wvySxJL8gE)

There's a bug or a mis-description of `ₔ` in the documentation:

> Push an extra copy of the arguments in swapped order, then run the operator. This only alters the behaviour of dyads.

While the description for `₌` reads:

> Push an extra copy of the arguments before executing the operator.

Unfortunately, `ₔ` only swaps the order of the arguments rather than pushing a swapped copy, otherwise `$:uC¦ₔZ$` would be 8 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL, 111 bytes

Added a line change to make it readable

```sql
WHILE @+@ like'_[a-z]%'
SELECT @=concat(s,left(@,1),len(@)-len(s))FROM(SELECT
replace(@,left(@,1),'')s)s
PRINT @
```

**[Try it online](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1249018/special-string-reformatting)**

Comment: I'm one to talk posting golfed C, but, how's that readable? T_T

Comment: @Noodle9 reading sql isn't that hard. The commands are simple and have nice long descriptive names - ill suited for golfing. But what I mean by readable, is that you don't have to scroll in order to see the whole text.

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 96 bytes

```
	I =INPUT
N	I LEN(1) . X	:F(O)
	N =
S	I X =	:F(B)
	N =N + 1	:(S)
B	O =O X N	:(N)
O	OUTPUT =O
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9NTwdbTLyA0hMsPyPRx9dMw1FTQU4jgtHLT8Nfk4vRTsOUKBspEKNiChJwgQn4K2gqGnFYawZpcTpz@Crb@QHk/IN9Pk8uf0z80BGgeUJDL1c/l//@SjMzizOLEvNSKxNyCnFQA)

```
	I =INPUT		;* Read input, set to I
N	I LEN(1) . X	:F(O)	;* Get the first character of I as X; if I is empty then goto O
	N =			;* set N to empty string (evaled as 0 in arithmetic)
S	I X =	:F(B)		;* remove the first occurrence of X from I. If none exist, goto B
	N =N + 1	:(S)	;* increment N and goto S
B	O =O X N	:(N)	;* Add to the output string and goto N to get the Next character
O	OUTPUT =O		;* print the result
END
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to @isaacg*

```
s+R/Qd{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v1g7SD8wpfr/f6X8otT0xLz81OLC0lQlAA)

```
s+R/Qd{
      {  Deduplicate: keep the first occurrence of each unique character
  R      For each of these unique characters:
 +        - append the character
   /Qd    - to its count in the original input
s        Join the resulting strings
```

Comment: `m+d` is equivalent to `+R`

Comment: @isaacg Thanks! I didn't realize that `R` and `d` could be used together

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ô!Ω;òá☺
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=9321ea3b95a001&i=potato%0Apqwertyuiop%0Athisisanexample%0Aoreganoesque%0Aaaaaaaabaaaaaa&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 31 bytes

```
+`(.)(.+)\1
$1$1$2
(.)\1*
$1$.&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYhLCoAwDAX3OYdIq1Co5@nCCEEL2vQTUU9flb5ZDPMyiQ9Y6zgro5UZtbPQ2Y8JvsPZ4S/T1xpZUBhiuijLc3qOIJsvvmCgG4@4E3CmFQNTSScBti1NLw) Link includes test cases, unusually without even needing a header. Explanation:

```
+`(.)(.+)\1
$1$1$2
```

Collect all repeated characters into a single run at the first appearance.

```
(.)\1*
$1$.&
```

Replace each run with its first character and its length.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 14 bytes

```
⭆Φθ¬№…θκι⁺ι№θι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYpBCoAgEEWv4nIEO0FLoV0RdAIRSWlozMag00@Gm/fh/eejK54ciqwlnQwbt9lnl2FKyKHAZdRCDJZqe@3rMdhI@deHNipp3bhivSEZ1aOraz2KZGLHJMODHw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
  θ             Input string
 Φ              Filter over characters
    №           Count of
        ι       Current character in
      θ         Input string
     …          Truncated to length
       κ        Current index
   ¬            Is zero
⭆               Map over unique characters and join
          ι     Current character
         ⁺      Concatenated with
           №    Count of
             ι  Current character in
            θ   Input string
                Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Kotlin](http://kotlinlang.org), <s>69</s> 67 bytes

```
fun String.f()=groupBy{it}.map{(a,b)->"$a"+b.size"}.joinToString("")
```

[Try it online!](https://pl.kotl.in/Yc2JZ5MDK)

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 57 bytes

```cs
s=>s.GroupBy(c=>c).Aggregate("",(r,g)=>r+g.Key+g.Count())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3PSgMxEMbP5ilC8JDgug/gmoVaUETBowfxEMNsGqhJmplYl7LPvjYNzmG@P3zws3hr0a@PJdh7pOyD63jTkU9cr6hH7J9yLOlhllaPVvUb5zI4QyCF6GTunNJjvnH9C8znv40lkFRqHRj7MZkTICHXPMDx45Od2JVIkQxF0VV7OEKmufiYLpl2Hj2aAL/mO@3h0sUKCxHwUFph2n01EWwZ2HQeGbvj8p/IfWhkVZHbGDDuoX/PnuDVB5DX4jmkQnf8VFcLfyvU4iRroRahBrasfw)

Answer (score 1):

## SimpleTemplate, <s>54</s> 47 bytes

This was a very easy, but incredibly fun challenge!

The code simply loops through every character and counts how many times it shows, and presents it all again.
Nothing fancy at all...

```
{@eachargv.0}{@incR.[_]}{@/}{@eachR}{@echo__,_}
```

Hey, I didn't say the code was readable!

---

Here's an ungolfed and readable version:

```
{@each argv.0 as char}
    {@inc by 1 result.[char]}
{@/}
{@each result as times key char}
    {@echo char, times}
{@/}
```

Should be easy to understand ...
`{@inc}` increments the value or creates a new one, if it doesn't exist. (this keeps key ordering).

---

You can try this on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a180782e659c29674fbb0d77dc82d90d238c6e08
Older version: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6ee5077eaf38ec445d84086cc07966026ca7c565

(There, you have an example on how to use this in a function, with multiple tests.)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
ṁS:os#¹u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOxmCr/GLlQztL////X5BfkliSDwA)

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 9 bytes

```
ṁ§:←osLk=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOxkPLrR61Tcgv9sm2/f//f0F@SWJJPgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `J`, 1 [byte](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ƈ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDNiU4OCZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PSUyMnBvdGF0byUyMiUyMC0lM0UlMjAlMjJwMW8ydDJhMSUyMiUwQSUyMnBxd2VydHl1aW9wJTIyJTIwLSUzRSUyMCUyMnAycTF3MWUxcjF0MXkxdTFpMW8xJTIyJTBBJTIydGhpc2lzYW5leGFtcGxlJTIyJTIwLSUzRSUyMCUyMnQxaDFpMnMyYTJuMWUyeDFtMXAxbDElMjIlMEElMjJvcmVnYW5vZXNxdWUlMjIlMjAtJTNFJTIwJTIybzJyMWUzZzFhMW4xczFxMXUxJTIyJTBBJTIyYWFhYWFhYWJhYWFhYWElMjIlMjAtJTNFJTIwJTIyYTEzYjElMjImZmxhZ3M9Q0o=)

LOL! Let me explain...

The `ƈ` built-in gets the count of each unique element in a list or string:

- For `"potato"` it gives `[["p",1], ["o",2], ["t",2], ["a",1]]`
- For `"aaaaaaabaaaaaa"` it gives `[["a",13], ["b",1]]`

Now this happens to be almost *exactly* what we need. The only thing left is just to join everything into a string, which is what the `J` flag does.

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 24 bytes

```arturo
$=>[tally&|map=>as|join]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?z0YmbL)

```
$=>[           ; a function where input is assigned to &
    tally&     ; create dictionary of occurrences in input
    |          ; then
    map=>as    ; convert to a block
    |          ; then
    join       ; join to a string
]              ; end function
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-pF -MList::Util+uniq`, 29 bytes

```perl
for$s(uniq@F){$\.=$s.s/$s//g}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z8tv0ilWKM0L7PQwU2zWiVGz1alWK9YX6VYXz@99v//gvySxJL8f/kFJZn5ecX/dQvc/uv6@mQWl1hZhZZk5miDNAIA)

Comment: This seems to put a 1 before every test case output except the first one

Comment: @Sqepia ah yeah, I meant to remove the other inputs, it's only one at a time. Sorry about that! It was counting the newlines...

Comment: makes sense, it works as intended then!

Comment: Put a `pop @F if $F [-1] =~ /\n/` in the Header section of TIO. That will strip off any unwanted newlines.

Comment: @Abigail hah, of course, thanks!

Comment: Shaved off a byte, getting rid of the loop and the module: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205936/72767

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-P`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>10</s> 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Would be 7 in Japt v2 but for a bug that costs 2 bytes to workaround.

```
¬â Ë+UèD
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVA&code=rOIgyytV6EQ&input=InBvdGF0byI)

Answer (score 0):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn), [9 bytes](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn)

```
yŽ▬ö░Ú^`"
```

[Try it!](https://zippymagician.github.io/Arn?code=fHs6e3wjfVw6QA==&input=cG90YXRvCnBxd2VydHl1aW9wCnRoaXNpc2FuZXhhbXBsZQpvcmVnYW5vZXNxdWUKYWFhYWFhYWJhYWFhYWE=&flags=)

## Explained

Unpacked: `|{:{|#}\:@`

```
     _         Variable initialized to STDIN; implied
  :@           Grouped by frequency
|{      }\     Folded with concatenation after mapping (key of _)
     :{        First entry
   |           Concatenated with
     #         Length
```